# TypeScript: Using typecasting for typeguard

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, casting, typeguards

I have class with constructor that can accept object of two types, and then based on what type of object it got, perform different actions.

I've seen that it's possible to use `as` keyword for that.
But it feels wrong to me.

```
export type Angle = {
    cos: number; 
    sin: number
}
```

```
export type VectorAngleInit = {
    angle: Angle,
    magnitude: number
}
```

```
export type VectorDInit = {
    dx: number,
    dy: number
}
```

```
export class Vector {
    #dx: number;
    #dy: number;
    constructor(init: VectorAngleInit | VectorDInit) {
        if ((init as VectorAngleInit)?.angle) {
            const angleInit = init as VectorAngleInit
            this.#dx = angleInit.magnitude * angleInit.angle.cos;
            this.#dy = angleInit.magnitude * angleInit.angle.sin;
        } else {
            const dInit = init as VectorDInit
            this.#dx = dInit.dx
            this.#dy = dInit.dy
        }
    }
}
```

Should i do that another way? If so, which way is better you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`in` operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) to check for the presence of `"angle"` in `init` and narrow `init` to the desired [union member](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) without a need for [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (what you're calling "casting"):

```
export class Vector {
  #dx: number;
  #dy: number;
  constructor(init: VectorAngleInit | VectorDInit) {
    if ("angle" in init) {
      this.#dx = init.magnitude * init.angle.cos;
      this.#dy = init.magnitude * init.angle.sin;
    } else {
      this.#dx = init.dx
      this.#dy = init.dy
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIgOYBsUG8CwAUMsggPYDOAXMiAK4C2ARtANxEkWg33NtEBfIkQgAPAA5koYZGACe4lADUICMFPTYIASRDAZAXmQFiyOJhw1NOADQdkDOBj1g6AEwg9GLKIOGExSWlZBWVVdSgAEV19ZCMTEjdRLz4oO1M3ORSfP0IRCSkZBCw4CgpkFTUpY3sAYiTs-lN6rNpvJpJyEAowKDoqqAAKUH0aSojrHRdkAB8K8KlolwBKYxISexJgGGRBgCJzLT3kUBOVtc31sAALYAoAOnrROLP9e8dnfXcUACpXsHuhxw93IFHYpnWsluDxaLxGAI+Lm+yD+8MBFgg9y4IHBkIEyAgWAoeEuJBud0eSThLnuSVJUIpsKMaMylyEpnZ7KAA)

Answer (score 2):

The thing you need is called [Type Predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)
which is an official way to narrow down your union type. It is a function with a special return type `x is SomeType` which is actually a boolean but informs `typescript` compiler that what you actually needs to do is to predicate the type rather than just return a boolean.

A sample related to your problem could be this:

First define your `type predicate` function

```js
export type VectorAngleInit = {
  angle: Angle
  magnitude: number
}

// type predicate predicating whether u is of type VectorAngleInit
export function isVectorAngleInit(u: unknown): u is VectorAngleInit {
  return !!u && typeof u === 'object' && (u as VectorAngleInit).angle instanceof Angle
}

export type VectorDInit = {
  dx: number
  dy: number
}

// type predicate predicating whether u is of type VectorDInit
export function isVectorDInit(u: unknown): u is VectorDInit {
  return !!u && typeof u === 'object' && typeof (u as VectorDInit).dx === 'number'
}
```

And then use it in your constructor:

```js
export class Vector {
  #dx: number
  #dy: number
  constructor(init: VectorAngleInit | VectorDInit) {
    if (isVectorAngleInit(init)) {
      // notice that type of `init` is auto inferred within if block
      this.#dx = init.magnitude * init.angle.cos
      this.#dy = init.magnitude * init.angle.sin  
    }
    if(isVectorDInit(init)){
      this.#dx = init.dx
      this.#dy = init.dy  
    }
  }
}
```